# How to connect a RFID reader and a LCD monitor with Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I need to connect a RFID reader with LC monitor and Raspberry Pi 3 so when a RFID detect a card LCD show a message, how do i connect these two with code?

I`ve been looking around internet but none actually answered my question or they was lost without answer. Code for checking a card is working alone same with a LCD, schowing messages as i tell.

```
import time
import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522


#Raspberry Pi pin setup
lcd_rs = 36
lcd_en = 24
lcd_d4 = 23
lcd_d5 = 17
lcd_d6 = 18
lcd_d7 = 22
lcd_backlight = 2

#Define LCD column and row size for 16x2 LCD.
lcd_columns = 16
lcd_rows = 2

lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCD(lcd_rs, lcd_en, lcd_d4, lcd_d5, lcd_d6, lcd_d7, lcd_columns, lcd_rows, lcd_backlight)
lcd.clear()
lcd.message('Hello\nWorld!')

#Wait 5 seconds
time.sleep(2.0)
lcd.clear()
text = raw_input("Type Something to be displayed: ")
lcd.message(text)


#Wait 5 seconds
time.sleep(2.0)
lcd.clear()
lcd.message('Goodbye\nWorld!')
time.sleep(2.0)
lcd.clear()
text = input(id)
lcd.message(id)
GPIO.cleanup()

reader = SimpleMFRC522()

print("Bring the card closer")
try:

        id, text = reader.read()
        print(id)
        print(text)
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

I expected that when a RFID read a card a message will pop-out on LCD monitor telling a message. Im new to this whole world of programming, any help will be thankful.

Comment: You may need to use the lcd.write_string() function I think and the sleep, clear. Make sure your wiring is right I would help but I'm not to familiar with the RFID library. But here are two links which may help https://learn.adafruit.com/drive-a-16x2-lcd-directly-with-a-raspberry-pi/overview https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/

Comment: Thanks for answer, im currently doing everything from pimylifeup and alone devices are working fine, but im very new to python and dont understand how this works from the coding side

Comment: Make sure your connections are right and perhaps this will help for you to learn more :                                               
       import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD
       help(LCD.Adafruit_CharLCD)